# How to invoke an object after some particular time?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Rate Us sprite should be displayed after 24 hours , counting from when first time app is launched . How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things you have to take care of.

When the first time the app is launched, get current time and save that object to NSUserDefaults. 
Whenever the user opens the application again, get the saved object in NSUserDefaults and see if it's been 24 hours. If so, show the RateUs, else set timer for the remaining time.

Better yet, use open source solutions like [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate).

Comment: installedDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"FirstLaunchTime"];
    if (installedDate == nil) // runs for the first time
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"FirstLaunchTime"];
    }
    else
    {
        NSDate *presentDate = [NSDate date];
        
        if ([installedDate compare:presentDate] == NSOrderedDescending && ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"is24hoursFinished"])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"is24hoursFinished"];
        }
    }
Thanks

Comment: @RevanthPrasad awesome.

Answer (score 0):

NSDate * installedDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"FirstLaunchTime"];

```
if (installedDate == nil)  {  // runs for the first time

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"FirstLaunchTime"];
    printf("\n First time \n");
}
else{

    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"is24hoursFinished"])
    {
        NSDate *presentDate = [NSDate date];

        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSUInteger units = NSDayCalendarUnit;

        NSDateComponents *Components = [gregorian components:units fromDate:installedDate toDate:presentDate options:0];
        NSInteger days = [Components day];

        printf("Number of days %ld",(long)days);

        if (days > 0)
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"is24hoursFinished"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }

    }

}
```